# Relational Database: Best practice regarding amount of queries per API call

Tags: sql, postgresql, api, redux, relational-database

I am working with React Native/Redux and an express/postgresql backend.

I have an api call to create a comment that returns the created comment as well as some of the information concerning the user.

Those are two different api calls.

Now I also need the updated comment count to send to the feed reducer so that the count is still correct when they close the comment tab.

I was wondering if it is still okay to have 3 queries in one API call and maybe more general/meta, if there might be a better solution to this if that isn't the case.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to do multiple queries in a single API call. You can do as many as are required to complete a single coherent interaction between the server and client.